# Where Can I Find "mkisofs" and "cdrecord" for Ubuntu 12.04 (e.g., iso9660 ufs)

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, ufs

Where can I find `mkisofs` and `cdrecord` for Ubuntu 12.04 (e.g., iso9660 ufs)?

Answer (score 5):

The good news is that if you are after the authentic `cdrecord` and `mkisofs` (rather than the Debian fork of these applications) Brandon Snider's PPA holds version of these great applications as far back as Ubuntu 12.04 *and forward in time to the most recent Ubuntu release*.

Add the PPA as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:brandonsnider/cdrtools
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the following from  Terminal window:

```
sudo apt-get install cdda2wav cdrecord mkisofs
```

And now you should be good to go *for any version of Ubuntu...*

Answer (score 0):

Install apt-file, then you can search for the package which contains them:

```
$ apt-file search mkisofs
aptoncd: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/APTonCD/core/mkisofs.py
debian-cd: /usr/share/debian-cd/tools/set_mkisofs_opts
genisoimage: /usr/bin/mkisofs
horde3: /usr/share/horde3/lib/VFS/ISOWriter/mkisofs.php
manpages-ja: /usr/share/man/ja/man8/mkisofs.8.gz
pybackpack: /usr/share/pyshared/pybackpack/mkisofs.py
rootstrap: /usr/lib/rootstrap/modules/mkisofs
```

Looks like genisoimage has `mkisofs`, and similarly, wodim has `cdrecord`.